# Create a 2d Array with a pattern in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, design-patterns, multidimensional-array

How I can create a 2D array that 1st column is integers between i and j and second column is a random number smaller than n

something like `a = [[6,4],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,3],[11,2]]`

I know `(i..j).to_a` creates my first column and `rand(n)` creates my second column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
i, j = 6, 11
(i..j).map { |x| [x, rand(10)] }
# => [[6, 8], [7, 6], [8, 4], [9, 9], [10, 0], [11, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Use a `map` to convert each item in your `i..j` `Range` into an `Array` with two entries:

```
i,j,n = 4,8,10
a = (i..j).map { |x| [x,rand(n)] }
```

Comment: A range is enumerable, no need to convert to array to map it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer (that got removed by poster), was almost right, just missing some calculations. It got rather harshly down-voted without comment, I'm re-posting here, with corrections to the maths, so that OP has something alternative:

```
i, j, n = 6, 11, 10    
Array.new( ­j - i + 1 ) { |x| [ x + i, rand(n)­] }
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative answer:

```
i=10
j=20
n=10
[(i..j).to_a , Array.new(j-i+1){rand(n)} ].transpose
```